# Open DateTimePicker C# control programmatically

Tags: winforms

How can I open the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) C# control programmatically?
I want to show the Calendar in the Datetime Picker control by sending keys to the control.
Is there a way we can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following

```
//part of the usings
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//declares
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool PostMessage(
IntPtr hWnd, // handle to destination window
Int32 msg, // message
Int32 wParam, // first message parameter
Int32 lParam // second message parameter
);

const Int32 WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

//method to call dropdown
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 x = dateTimePicker1.Width - 10;
    Int32 y = dateTimePicker1.Height / 2;
    Int32 lParam = x + y * 0x00010000;

    PostMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1,lParam);

}
```

Comment: This appears to be broken on Windows 7 or .NET35. The calendar pops up, but it is not responsive. Hovering over the control doesn't do anything, and when you click on a date, the calendar disappears but doesn't update the .Value of the DateTimePicker control.

Comment: Not working in Windows 10 64bit. Calendar drops down but is not responsive. It is missing something..

Answer (score 5):

On my system (Windows 7, .NET 35) the other solutions did not work. I found another solution on a MS discussion site that did work.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Extensions
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private const uint WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

    public static void Open(this DateTimePicker obj)
    {
        SendMessage(obj.Handle, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, (int)Keys.Down, 0);
    }
}
```

Source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f2f0b213-d57a-46de-b924-e21b7ac0882e/programmatically-open-the-calendar-of-the-datetimepicker-control?forum=winforms

Usage:

```
dateTimePicker1.Open();
```

Warnings. This will not work if the `dateTimePicker1` is a Control on `DataGridView` (ie if you try to make a pop-up DatePicker on the DGV). It does work if the Control is added to the `Form` instead.  What will happen is that the synthesized cursor "down" event will be swallowed by the DGV, and will move the current cell pointer down one instead of drop-drop the Calendar of the DTP.

Comment: It is working perfect for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to [astander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144424/astander) for providing the solution, which makes a very nice extension:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Extensions {

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 wMsg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

  public static void Open(this DateTimePicker obj) {
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    int width = obj.Width - 10;
    int height = obj.Height / 2;
    int lParam = width + height * 0x00010000; // VooDoo to shift height
    PostMessage(obj.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, lParam);
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
dateTimePicker1.Open();
```

This way, you can reuse your Extension anytime you'd like, over and over, in any form using any DateTimePicker control.

Comment: just and FYI, this did *NOT* work for me, the calendar opens but as soon as user clicks anywhere it immediately closes, pretty useless.

Comment: FYI we need `PostMessage(obj.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 1, lParam);` after WM_LBUTTONDOWN, in order to accept mouse click.

Answer (score 2):

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f2f0b213-d57a-46de-b924-e21b7ac0882e/programmatically-open-the-calendar-of-the-datetimepicker-control?forum=winforms
Refer answer by David M Morton https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/david%20m%20morton/?ws=usercard-mini

```
//DateTimePicker dtpicker
dtpicker.Select();
SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
```

"%{DOWN}" Key combination - Alt key(%) +Down arrow
code to programmatically trigger key down event for datetimepicker
(particularly the event of click on the dropdown arrow in a datetimepicker)

Comment: Works nicely, simple, clear!!!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is mostly correct, however you should also use:

`PostMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 1,lParam);`

After posting the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` event.

Also, obviously `WM_LBUTTONUP` must be previously defined:

`const Int32 WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;`

So my answer is:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//declares
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool PostMessage(
IntPtr hWnd, // handle to destination window
Int32 msg, // message
Int32 wParam, // first message parameter
Int32 lParam // second message parameter
);

const Int32 WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
const Int32 WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

//method to call dropdown
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 x = dateTimePicker1.Width - 10;
    Int32 y = dateTimePicker1.Height / 2;
    Int32 lParam = x + y * 0x00010000;

    PostMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1,lParam);
    PostMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 1,lParam);
}
```

This avoids Mark Lakata's bug in Windows 7 and/or .NET 3.5.

The reasoning is simple: the original code simulates a mouse button down event, but doesn't get the mouse button up again as we would when we click the button.

In that regard, you can try it out yourself: if you press the left mouse button to open a `DateTimePicker` and don't release the button, you also won't be able to use the control.

**Edit:** Adapting jp2code's answer:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Extensions {

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 wMsg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

  public static void Open(this DateTimePicker obj) {
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
    int width = obj.Width - 10;
    int height = obj.Height / 2;
    int lParam = width + height * 0x00010000; // VooDoo to shift height
    PostMessage(obj.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, lParam);
    PostMessage(obj.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 1, lParam);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked some of the previous ideas and finished with this (tested) Mix:

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static void Open(this DateTimePicker obj)
    {
        obj.Select();
        SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
dateTimePicker1.Open();    
dateTimePicker2.Open();
```