# DateTimePicker C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open DateTime picker C# control programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427962/open-datetime-picker-c-sharp-control-programatically)

I have  a `DateTimePicker` control on my form and what I want is when the user clicks on the text field of that `DateTimePicker` the calendar should open not just on the calendars icon's click.

For example:

```
private void dateTimePickerEndDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePickerEndDate.OpenCalendar();
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Any help and assistance will do!

Comment: +1 This may be a duplicate, but the duplicate did not pull up when I searched `open datetimepicker control`; this one did.

Answer (score 0):

Can you handle any of the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.click.aspx), [`MouseClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mouseclick.aspx) or [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx) events on the `DateTimePicker`? If so, you should be able to determine the source of the click and open the calendar if you deem it necessary.

Comment: I can handle the mousedown event. But how do I open the calendar?

Comment: You cannot do this simply - the `DateTimePicker` control doesn't expose that sort of functionality to the user. Instead, refer to the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427962/open-datetime-picker-c-sharp-control-programatically) that Cody Gray posted. I've tested the method and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Enter' event and write your code in the corresponding handler. 
Click on the text field and in the properties window click the event handler tab. Here you can double click on the 'Enter' event to add the handler in your code. Hope this helps!

Comment: SO how do i open the calendar? The event hadler in my question was just an example